# is there a way to access kwargs dict without explicitly using it with def(**kwargs)?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Let's say that we have a function declaration like

```
def myfunc(a=None,b=None):
    as_dict = {"a": a,
               "b": b,
              }
    print a * b
    some_other_function_that_takes_a_dict(as_dict)
```

Is there a way to capture the keyword arguments as a dict without changing the `def myfunc(...)`, I mean I can do

```
 def myfunc(**kwargs):
    print kwargs['a'] * kwargs['b']
    some_other_function_that_takes_a_dict(kwargs)
```

But if I want to keep the function signature for clarity and documentation, do I have any other way to get the keyword arguments as a dict. I tried to search for magic variables, etc but I can see any that does that.

Just to be clear I'm search for something like

```
def myfunc(a=None,b=None):
    print a * b
    some_other_function_that_takes_a_dict(__kwargs__)
```

is there a magical `__kwargs__` of some sort in python?

Comment: just use `locals()` in your function     `kwargs = locals()`

Comment: right! if you make this an answer instead of a comment I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have kwargs in your function just use `locals`

```
def my_func(a=None,b=None):
    kwargs = locals()
    print (kwargs["a"] * kwargs["b"])

In [5]: my_func(10,2)
20
```

Comment: @falsetru *and*, if you have non-keyword arguments too, you can combine this method with falsetru's answer to figure out which are which. (falsetru, you should undelete your answer, as it's useful in this particular situation)

Comment: @goncalopp, if the OP wants to access by key it will still work if there are non keyword args but I am not sure if that is the case

Comment: Indeed, it will work for plain access, but the list of keyword-arguments would be *wrong* - which may or not matter, depending on what is done with it later. As you said, this is enough for OP's needs, though.

Comment: also, it may be worth mentioning that one should copy (`dict(locals())`), to prevent unintended side effects by having other functions assigning to local variables

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see what was @falsetrue answer, this answer works for me because I only have kwargs in my func. Great to know about `locals()`

Comment: @goncalopp, can you please post answer, I'm curious about what the alternative was.

Comment: @ecerulm I just did. It's much more involved, `locals` would be the preferred solution if you only have keyword arguments, or you're happy getting other variables too.

Answer (score 1):

Extending Padraic Cunningham's answer to work with functions that have non-keyword arguments:

```
from inspect import getargspec

def get_function_kwargs( f, f_locals ):
    argspec= getargspec(f)
    kwargs_keys = argspec[0][-len(argspec[3]):] #get only arguments with defaults
    return  {k:f_locals[k] for k in kwargs_keys}

def my_func(a, b=1, c=2):
    kwargs= get_function_kwargs( my_func, locals() )
    print kwargs
```

Answer (score 0):

Be explicit. Build the dictionary from just those variables that `other` needs.

```
def myfunc(a=None, b=None):
    other({'a': a, 'b': b})
```